# How to apply auto complete to the drop down in MVC4?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, autocomplete

Hi I  want to apply auto complete to the  drop down. I will explain my issue clearly . I  have two drop down in my view which is mentioned below.

[image: Drop Downs]

Here i kept the two drop down in selection mode. That is i have to scroll and select the value. This method is suitable for limited no of values. But  the field have more than 1000  values means it is difficult  me to find the value by  scrolling,searching and selecting the value. so i decided to change the drop down as auto complete  drop down

**My View**

```
 @Html.Label("Customer Name", new { @class = "control-label" })
 @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CustomerID, new SelectList(string.Empty, "Value", "Text"), "Please select a Customer", new { @class = "form-control required", type = "text" })

 @Html.Label("Contact Person", new { @class = "control-label" })
 @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CustomerContactID, new SelectList(string.Empty, "Value", "Text"), "Please select a ContactPerson", new { @class = "form-control", type = "text", id = "CustomerContactID" })
```

**My J-query**

```
<script>
$(function () {
    $.ajax(
      '@Url.Action("GetCustomers", "VisitorsForm")',{
          type: "GET",
          datatype: "Json",
          success: function (data) {
              $.each(data, function (index, value) {
                  $('#CustomerID').append('<option value="' + value.CustomerID + '">' + value.DisplayName + '</option>');
              });
          }
      });
});

        $('#CustomerID').change(function () {
        $('#CustomerContactID').empty();
        $.ajax(
            '@Url.Action("GetContactPersobByCustomerId", "VisitorsForm")',{
                type: "POST",
                datatype: "Json",
                data: { CustomerID: $('#CustomerID').val() },
                success: function (data) {
                $('#CustomerContactID').append($('<option></option>').val('').text('Please select'));
                $.each(data, function (index, value) {
                $('#CustomerContactID').append('<option value="' + value.CustomerContactID + '">' + value.ContactReference + '</option>');
                  });

                }
            });
  });
```

Actually i kept these two drop down as cascading drop down. Now any one tell me how to do this task. Please any one give me the solution to this problem i search many articles for this task but  many task is only there for text box only.  so any one give me solution.

Advance Thanks.

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://select2.github.io/examples.html) javascript library [select2](https://select2.github.io/examples.html)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a textbox on top of your dropdown list. Whenever enter some text in textbox u can bind the dropdownlist based on that text on key up and key down event

Comment: can you explain your  answer with one eg mukal